# NetSuite nlapiSubmitField for a List/Record

Tags: netsuite

I am having trouble with a RESTlet I am working on. I am bringing in a list of individuals who are canceling their service. I need to then go through the list, set their accounts to cancelled, and give a reason why it is cancelled in symptom field called "custrecord_scrapsymptomcode". The symptom field is of type "List/Record" and refers to one of the 20 items in a list called "Symptoms".

I am able to iterate through the individuals and set multiple fields on their record, however I am not able to set the value of the "Symptoms" field, which is supposed to be one of the values from the list. When I attempt to do so I receive an error that "that record is not editable".

I have tried the following strategies so far with no luck:

```
nlapiSubmitField('customrecord_customer', j, 'custrecord_scrapsymptomcode', s);
```

and

```
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('customrecord_customer', j); 
nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_scrapsymptomcode', s);
nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
```

'customrecord_customer' is the ID of the record type I am attempting to change

'j' is the internal ID of the customer record I am attempting to edit

'custrecord_scrapsymptomcode' is the ID of the field that I am attempting to set

's' is the symptom or reason for cancellation. It should be an item from the list of symptoms. I am not exactly sure why but it seems to only want an integer value.

Is there a better way to set this field value given that it is an item of a list? Is the error I am receiving related to the way I am scripting the record or it this more of a configuration/permissions issue with my system? I should have full admin rights on my system if that is helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: The code you are using looks correct. Check for any script or workflow deployed on the record. Check if any client script is attached to the custom form. Also check the permissions in that record type.

Comment: There are no client side or server side scripts I can find that would prevent me from editing the record fields. This is a RESTlet so I do not expect a form or UI to be involved. The record should have no permissions required to edit the fields according to the page on the record type. Thank you for the info, I am still struggling with this permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('customrecord_customer', j); 
rec.setFieldValue('custrecord_scrapsymptomcode', s);
nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);
```

Comment: I tried that before also and get the same error. I have no problems with the setFieldValue function calls but receive the error when it executes the nlapiSubmitRecord function call.

Comment: The code I gave is correct. Check if the id 's' is valid or not.Is it present in the custom list ?

"It should be an item from the list of symptoms. I am not exactly sure why but it seems to only want an integer value."
setValue takes the internal id
setText takes the test value

Answer (score 0):

```
nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_scrapsymptomcode', s);
```

This will not work in a restlet - there is no 'current record'.

```
rec.setFieldValue('custrecord_scrapsymptomcode', s)
```

will set the value on the record you have just loaded.

As for your error - that might be a permissions error - check the role that the restlet is executing as, and check the default form for that role, and make sure that this particular custom record is editable by that role.

Answer (score -1):

The custom field ids are prefixed with **custentity**. Please make sure that you are using the correct internalId of the field.